# Raising an error if a variable is not created during class initalization

Tags: python, error-handling

I would like to properly raise an error if `self._header` was not created when I initialize a `NewFile` object.

This is working now, but perhaps there is more formal way of catching the error below:

```
class NewFile(object):
    """ Docstring """

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.localdir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents'
        self.filename = filename
        self.filepath = os.path.join(self.localdir, self.filename)
        self._data = []

        try:
            with open(self.filepath, 'rU') as c:
                rows = csv.reader(c)
                for row in rows:
                    row[:] = [r.lower().strip() for r in row]

                    if row[0].startswith('name'):
                        self._header = row     # Create Header Variable

                    self._data.append(row)

        except IOError:
            raise IOError(
                '"{}" not found in "{}"'.format(self.filename, self.localdir))

        # I would like to raise error if "self._header" was not created
        try:
            self._header
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError(
                'No Header not found in "{}"'.format(self.filename))


def main():
    f = 'samplefile.csv'    
    new = NewFile(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you asking about something that hasn't yet been implemented?

Comment: @Jamal i think it has been implemented, but they want to see if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You can also use `if not hasattr(self, '_header')`, and it may even start a flame war on the problems and benefits of duck-typing, and keep us entertained for hours! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You got the arrow anti-pattern:

```
    try:
        with open(self.filepath, 'rU') as c:
            rows = csv.reader(c)
            for row in rows:
                row[:] = [r.lower().strip() for r in row]

                if row[0].startswith('name'):
                    self._header = row     # Create Header Variable

                self._data.append(row)

    except IOError:
        raise IOError(
            '"{}" not found in "{}"'.format(self.filename, self.localdir))
```

4 levels of nesting..., instead, perform exception handling before:

```
try:
    with open(self.filepath, 'rU') as c:
        rows = csv.reader(c)
except IOError:
    raise IOError(
       '"{}" not found in "{}"'.format(self.filename, self.localdir))
```

Data processing comes later, so now you have 2 levels of nesting before and 2 levels of nesting after, that is much better than 4 levels of nesting in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is how I'd do it, attempt to call the attribute and catch the potential error. However I think you shouldn't raise an `AttributeError`. `AttributeError`s are used for when the user tries to access or set an attribute that doesn't exist. Just because that's the error you're catching doesn't mean it's the most suitable one to display to the user. What is important is that what the user sees will tell them what to fix to get a valid output.

In this case, the reason you might not have a `_header` is if a filename is passed that doesn't have one. In that case, I would call it a `ValueError` and explain why one may not have been found. You've already covered the `IOError`, so that means that the file is missing the line with `'name'` that denotes a header. So tell the user that.

```
except AttributeError:
    raise ValueError(
        'Header with 'name' not found in "{}"'.format(self.filename))
```

After all it is possible that there is *a* header that either leaves out `'name'`, or misspells it. Any difference from your prescribed format will produce this error and the specificity will help a user find the actual problem.

One other note, I advise you find a better classname than `NewFile`. Try to indicate what the purpose of the file might be or what makes your file class different and useful.